# Change xlabel and remove title from pgfplots plot

Tags: pgfplots

I got the Tex file. But it is not compiling due to error  `\pgfplotsset{width=12cm,compat=1.12}`.

A minute change I want. A graph is all right but I want to replace the caption of X- axis namely " N=v(PN) " by " $n=V(P_n)$ " and I want to remove the title. So please do those changes in Tex file and please kindly send me the graph as pdf file or other..
The tex file is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\pgfplotsset{width=12cm,compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
%!tikz source begin
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{
    every pin/.style={fill=yellow!50!white,rectangle,rounded corners=3pt,font=\tiny},
    small dot/.style={fill=black,circle,scale=0.3}
  }
\begin{axis}[
        y label style={rotate=-90},
        title=My title,
        ylabel = $\gamma_g^e$,
        xlabel = {N=$|v(PN)|$},
        ymin=0,xmin=0,
        ymax=15,xmax=19
]
\addplot[
   red,
   domain=2:18,
   samples=17,
]
{floor((x+2)/2};
\addplot[blue, ] coordinates{(2,4) (6,4) (7,5)};
\addplot[
   blue,
   domain=7:18,
   samples=13,
]
{ceil(2*(x/3)};
\node[small dot,pin=-30:{$\gamma_g^e(P_6\Box P_2) = \gamma_g^e(P_6)\gamma_g^e(P_2)$}] at (6,4) {};
\legend{$\gamma_g^e(P_6\Box P_2)$,$\gamma_g^e(P_n)\gamma_g^e(P_2)$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: graph of the given tex file]

Answer (score 1):

To eliminate the title, just comment out the `title=`:

```
%title=My title,
```

and to get the desired `xlabel` change the `xlabel=`:

```
xlabel = {$n=V(P_n)$}
```

### Notes:

- Since the `N=` is part of the equation it should also be in math mode. So, instead of using `N=$|v(PN)|$` you should have `$N=|v(PN)|$`.
- I don't see any reason why `\pgfplotsset{width=12cm,compat=1.12}` should be causing a problem. I'd suggest you update your packages or better just use a current release such as TeXLive2015.  Alternatively, you could try to move the `width=12cm` to be an option to `\begin{axis}`.

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\pgfplotsset{width=12cm,compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
%!tikz source begin
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{
    every pin/.style={fill=yellow!50!white,rectangle,rounded corners=3pt,font=\tiny},
    small dot/.style={fill=black,circle,scale=0.3}
  }
\begin{axis}[
        y label style={rotate=-90},
        %title=My title,
        ylabel = $\gamma_g^e$,
        xlabel = {$n=V(P_n)$},
        ymin=0,xmin=0,
        ymax=15,xmax=19
]
\addplot[
   red,
   domain=2:18,
   samples=17,
]
{floor((x+2)/2};
\addplot[blue, ] coordinates{(2,4) (6,4) (7,5)};
\addplot[
   blue,
   domain=7:18,
   samples=13,
]
{ceil(2*(x/3)};
\node[small dot,pin=-30:{$\gamma_g^e(P_6\Box P_2) = \gamma_g^e(P_6)\gamma_g^e(P_2)$}] at (6,4) {};
\legend{$\gamma_g^e(P_6\Box P_2)$,$\gamma_g^e(P_n)\gamma_g^e(P_2)$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. As you suggested to update my version but I could not because some problem. So I am not able to edit in tex file and compile in my laptop. So I kindly request you to edit in tex file and send me the graph with that minute change. I have identified a mistake in legend which is

Comment: As you suggested to update my version but I could not because some problem. So I am not able to edit in tex file and compile in my laptop. So I kindly request you to edit in tex file and send me the graph with that minute change. I have identified a mistake in legend which is " \legend{$\gamma_g^e(P_6\Box P_2)$,$\gamma_g^e(P_n)\gamma_g^e(P_2)$} ". It should be edited to " \legend{$\gamma_g^e(P_n\Box P_2)$,$\gamma_g^e(P_n)\gamma_g^e(P_2)$} " . That is replace " (P_6\Box P_2) "  by " (P_n\Box P_2) " . Please kindly send me the new edited graph.

Comment: @kalpeshmpopat: You can obtain the image of the graph from this answer. Please post a specific question with details about _some problem_ with the update. That way you will have s/w that works and can do your own edits in the future.

Comment: I am not able to obtain the image of the edited graph. So please kindly do a minute edit as i mentioned as above and please kindly send me the edited image of graph. I want to put this image as pdf file in my paper as soon as possible. So please kindly send me the edited image of the graph.